# Can you save everyone in Haven?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

During the invasion, you are tasked with rescuing several people. However, no matter how many times I try, I can never seem to save them all. Is this intended or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can be done, even on Nightmare. It is imperative that you follow a fairly precise route, though.

1. Clear the doorway at the forge so Harritt can get his things.
2. Enter the gates and turn right to save Lysette.
3. Head back the way you came and go up the next set of stairs. Wait for the enemies to come to you to avoid starting the timer for Flissa.
4. Head into the tavern by the closest door and rescue Flissa. Ignore enemies when you do this.
5. Head back out by the same door. Do NOT use the door next to Flissa -- you'll trigger the explosive pots too soon. You can now finish off the enemies near the tavern but stay away from the pots area.
6. Then, head straight up the path towards the pots. Rescue Adan first, then Minaeve. It can be done, but it is a very narrow window.
7. Then go to the requisitions area and rescue the woman (Threnn) there.
8. Head back down the stairs to save Seggrit from the burning building. The door is blocked so you'll have to climb a ladder and jump over to the log piles and jump inside the building.

The key thing is to avoid entering the trigger area until you're ready. As soon as you hit the trigger boundary, one of your companions will say they hear a survivor. When that happens, drop everything and run to the rescue.

Comment: Just re-did the quest on my second playthrough, worked like a charm.

Comment: With Seggrit's building, I just smashed the door down with my mace. Worked fine.

Comment: In addition to (6), you can send party members to both Adan and Minaeve (set them to hold position), and then you can jump from one party member to the other instead of running around the pots. This gives you 1-2 seconds of leeway.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible, but you seriously need to be quick on your feet. For the woman in the tavern and the two up by the eastern side, you just need to completely disregard the enemies and rush to save them before they die, because their timers are really short. Then for Threnn up at the Chantry, you just need to keep her alive as best as you can in the fight, and then for the guy down in the burning house, you need to break the door open. The key is not triggering them until you're ready to save them since their timers don't start until they become an objective.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the tactical camera to save Flissa, Minaeve and Adan using your party members at the same time (you need to ignore the enemies). Careful not to go with the left stair near the tavern as it will trigger saving Threnn quest. The right stair won't trigger it, save Seggrit last by using the ladder to go inside his house.

Some of the party members will say we rallied everyone or something similar if you have saved all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Jonathan Fingland's route and it worked, although you don't actually save everyone by reviving them manually. This is the case for Lysette and Threnn, who apparently are well enough to fight with you. Pause and use tactical screen to view them, they will also greet you once the fight is over before running for the Chantry, and that tells you they survived the fight.

Answer (score 1):

My method was this (and best to use one of each class in party for the whole game)

1. Harrit, use a warrior and smash boxes
2. Lysette
3. Segrrit, again warrior to smash boxes
4. Flissa
5. Adan
6. Minaeve
7. Therrn

I have noticed a glitch when both using tactical camera, and not using it. (Note: I play on the PS3).

Sometimes you have to click twice on the person to actually save them. This is a pain when trying to save Adan and Minaeve. 
My suggestion is to **save** after saving Flissa in the tavern. That way you can redo it if you fail both.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. Me and a mate are playing through at the same time, roughly same stats etc., and we could only save the woman in the burning building (Flissa) then Lysette (the Templar  woman) and the two guys just before you get forced into the main base bit. The healer woman seemed to die from the explosions regardless of how fast you got to her but I'm still not sure if that's scripted.

I don't think you can save anyone else though, I did try looking for the horse master guy but I think he's one of the dead outside the pen.

Using revive on her does not work either, it's a manual revive regardless of class.
Tried by me and my mate

Comment: No, it's absolutely possible to help Harritt and save every one else (all 6 of them).